# Map with custom key in Groovy vs Java

Tags: java, groovy

I want to use a map in Groovy where the keys will be instances of an unmutable class.

This is something I do often in Java and it works fine, like in this example class:

```
public class TestMap {
    static final class Point {
        final int x; final int y;
        public Point(int x, int y) {this.x = x;this.y = y;}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Point, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        final Point origin = new Point(0, 0);
        map.put(origin, "hello world !" );
        if(!map.containsKey(origin))
            throw new RuntimeException("can't find key origin in the map");
        if(!map.containsKey(new Point(0,0))) {
            throw new RuntimeException("can't find new key(0,0) in the map");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to achieve the same thing with Groovy, it doesn't work. 
Why ?
Here is a sample non working example in Groovy:

```
class Point { 
    final int x; final int y
    Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y }
    public String toString() { return "{x=$x, y=$y}" }
}

def origin = new Point(0, 0)
def map = [(origin): "hello"] 
map[(new Point(1,1))] = "world"
map.put(new Point(2,2),  "!")

assert map.containsKey(origin) // this works: when it's the same ref
assert map.containsKey(new Point(0,0))
assert map.containsKey(new Point(1,1))
assert map.containsKey(new Point(2,2))
assert !map.containsKey(new Point(3,3))
```

Comment: Your Java version doesn't work either.  See [here](https://ideone.com/hUsD2H).

Answer (score 5):

You need to have an `equals` and `hashCode` method on your `Point` class so that the instances can be found as keys in the `HashMap`

You can do this quickly by adding an annotation in Groovy:

```
import groovy.transform.*

@EqualsAndHashCode
class Point { 
    final int x; final int y
    Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y }
    public String toString() { return "{x=$x, y=$y}" }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. You need `equals()` and `hashCode()` there too. Which is why your Java code throws `RuntimeException: can't find new key(0,0) in the map`.

Comment: Andreas is right; the Java code given creates a compromised map (as shown in the [example output](https://ideone.com/hUsD2H) I gave in my comment on the question).  This is the right answer.